# How to edit and preview a site on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty?

Tags: 14.04

I don't have admin access to the site, just the address. If I try to save it and open it from the .html file, it looks completely different from the actual site, I suppose my first question is: why is that? Mainly, I'm trying to find a way to make changes to the site and preview said changes in a convenient manner possibly using Filezilla. I don't have a web host, though I know there are ones that are free but for the purposes of previewing the site in the way it appears in the browser, is that even necessary?

Answer (score 0):

To view a local html page exactly like it looks on the web server, you would need to download not just the html file but all associated components, like .css files, .js scripts, webfont files, etc, and even then it is possible for a web page to change its outlook in real time. This is possible to do in a browser.

Also keep in mind that by the time the html file arrives in your computer, all server-side processing has been applied, so what is stored in the server may differ significantly from what you see.

If you use Chrome or Firefox, saving a web page as "Webpage (complete)" will store the html page as a single file and additionally create a folder, in the same location and with the same name, with as many associated files as it can find. The browser will also modify the links in the html page to point to the local files, rather than the files on the server. But even then, the page may be too complex to render exactly like the web page.